# Use Elasticsearch Index from newer Version

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to use (e.g. reindex) an existing index from a newer Elasticsearch version? I tried to do it via the snapshots API, but that fails with:

> the snapshot was created with Elasticsearch version [7.5.0] which is higher than the version of this node [7.4.2]

The reason we need to use the newer index is that we want to experiment with a plugin that is not yet available for the new version, but the experiments must be done on data indexed by the newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snapshot API won't work since you are trying to restore the index on an instance older than the instance that created the index.

You will need to have your index data on a 7.5 instance and use the `reindex` API on a 7.4.2 instance to [reindex from remote](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote)

It is something like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://7-5-remote-host:9200"
    },
    "index": "source"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest"
  }
}
```

You can also use a logstash pipeline to read from your 7.5 instance and index on your 7.4.2 instance.

Something like this:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://7-5-instance:9200"
    index => "your-index"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://7-4-instance:9200"
    index => "your-index"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great. Additionally, before reindexing I had to copy setting incl. analyzers and mappings from the 7.5 instance in order to not produce any errors.